# Restrict type of class passed to parameter using generics without casting

Tags: java, generics

Let's assume I have an an implementation that is able to convert a string of a certain format into an object of the specified class...

```
public interface Translator {
    <T> T convertToObject(Class<T> clazz, String msg);
}
```

I have a class that uses it as follows:

```
public <T> T proccessMessage(Class<? extends Response> responseCls,String msg) {
    return (T) translator.convertToObject(responseCls, msg); 
}
```

Is there a way to do this without casting? My intention is to restrict the processMessage to only accept Response types. The response type is a marker interface. Thanks!

Comment: You cannot cast using a type parameter, because come runtime the JVM has no knowledge of type parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the same type for the class passed as parameter to translator and the returned type, because that's how it's defined in the interface:

```
public <T extends Response> T proccessMessage(Class<T> responseCls,String msg) {
    return translator.convertToObject(responseCls, msg); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you restrict the class parameter to be a subclass of `Response`, I believe your method signature should look like this:

```
public <T extends Response>
    T proccessMessage(Class<? extends T> responseCls, String msg)
{
    return translator.convertToObject(responseCls, msg);
}
```

This way you get the proper return type and it compiles without type casting.